# How can I run tests in the same script in parallel?

Tags: perl

I have a few test scripts each of which has about 4-5 tests each. The good thing about these tests are that they don't interfere with each other and can run in parallel. I found that I was able to run these tests in parallel using the prove tool but the tests in the individual scripts still ran serially.

For example

```
Test_A.t    Test_B.t     
 |_ test1    |_ test3
 |_ test2    |_ test4
```

- test1 and test3 started at the same time when I used prove -j9.
- test2 ran after test1 was done.
- test4 ran after test3 was done.

*I'd like to run test1, test2, test3 and test4 in parallel. Any ideas?*

Comment: I could have one .t file per test but that solution is far from elegant

Comment: Are these ordinary Test::More style tests?

Comment: The tests are written using Test::Class but I can convert them to use Test::More only if necessary.

Comment: Both [Test::More](http://p3rl.org/Test::More) and [Test::Class](http://p3rl.org/Test::Class) are based around [Test::Builder](http://p3rl.org/Test::Builder), so changing it from one style to the other won't help here.